# Spring Integration Java DSL: strategy to handle errors / exceptions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

How do I approach an error handling in Java DSL flows?

Suppose I have a simple flow that writes to Rabbit (or to a database).

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow setupRabbitFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(publishSubscribeChannel)
            .handle((p, h) -> rabbitPublishActivator.publishToRabbit(p))
            .get();
}
```

Such an operation may result in an error due to database issues or intermediary connection failure.

How could I enhance flow declaration towards actions taken if some exception happens within the "publishToRabbit" step?

Comment: why dont you simply log the exception in `publishToRabbit` method?

Comment: Simply logging is not enough, I might want to call some logic to re-try sending later for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you talk about retry and similar, you should take a look into [RequestHandlerRetryAdvice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#retry-advice).

On the other hand the `.handle()` has the second argument - endpoint configurer. There is you can specify `.advice()`:

```
.handle((GenericHandler<?>) (p, h) -> {
                    throw new RuntimeException("intentional");
                }, e -> e.advice(retryAdvice()))

    @Bean
    public RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice() {
        RequestHandlerRetryAdvice requestHandlerRetryAdvice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
        requestHandlerRetryAdvice.setRecoveryCallback(new ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer(recoveryChannel()));
        return requestHandlerRetryAdvice;
    }
```

Comment: Also, if your `publishToRabbit` uses a `RabbitTemplate`, you can configure it with a `RetryTemplate`.

Comment: Thank you, and if I just need to handle an error, how I can configure that?

Comment: There is `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` on the matter: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice